# How could I echo a JSON format object in PHP passed through python in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: php, python, json, encoding, jupyter-notebook

This is my python (.ipynb) code:

```
import requests
import json

url='http://localhost/test.php'
payload = {'name':'Borja'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
print(r.url)
print(r.encoding)
print(r.content)
print(r.text)
```

This is the output of the .ipynb:
[image: .ipynb output]

and this is my php code:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");

echo "$json";

$json1=json_encode($json);

echo "<h1>$json1</h1>";

?>
```

This is what i get from the php:

[image: php output]

Comment: Check [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function

Comment: it didn't work i get the same result

Comment: what do you **want** PHP's output to be?

Comment: the sent JSON object. I would like to grab it after with ajax.

Comment: probably i haven't understood the concepts but it's just an example on which i would like to get a parameter from python in php and showin' it on a web page without having to refresh the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTTP method for the request is POST, you can directly encode the POST array.

```
<?php

$json = json_encode($_POST);

echo "<h1>{$json}</h1>";

?>
```

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work. The result is [] two brackets. Thank you anyway!